# Implement this form of UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView with custom cells.

I want to implement this kind of UIScrollView in every cell.

The maximum number of image I can have in every scrollView is 5. it can be less, but not more.

[image]

I have the graphics and everything. I want to implement it with UIPageControl so the current image will be marked in the pageControl and so I can change its frame to the green glow.

I'm using this code right now in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,202,295,91)];
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;


NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[[[self.campArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"images"]count]; i++) {


    UIImageView * imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*130, 0, 108, 92)];

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-03.png"]];

    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 96, 81)];
    [imgV setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[self.campArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"images"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"thumbnailURL"]]];

    imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    imgV.tag=i+1;

    [imageView  addSubview:imgV];

    [imageArray addObject:imageView];

    [imageView release];
    [imgV release];

}



NSInteger numberOfViews = imageArray.count
;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

    [self.scrollView addSubview:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoomImage)];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];   


self.scrollView.tag = [indexPath row];

UIPageControl *pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 108, 81)];

pgCtr.numberOfPages=numberOfViews;
pgCtr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
[cell.contentView addSubview:pgCtr];

//set the scroll view content size
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(130 * 
                                         numberOfViews, 
                                         self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
//add the scrollview to this view
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];
return cell;
```

Thanks!

Comment: why are using a table for that? I think you can simply go with the scroll view and the page control. Besides, it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @sergio I'm using tableView because I have more things in addition to the scrollView in every cell. And the problem is that I dont know how to implement this kind of scrollView like in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by making a `UIScrollView` setting up your `UIImageView` objects in the scroll view as desired.

When the user scrolls around the images and lets go, you'll want the image closest to the center to center itself and become the highlighted image. We'll need to handle that ourselves. So create a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement the method `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:`

Our next problem is figuring out how to make the scrolling slow to a stop centered on the nearest image. This is a little tricky, but quite possible. We need to know a few things. Like our visible area of the scroll view is really just a moving window on a bigger picture. We need to know where this window is right now and we need to know  where all the items are in the big picture.

Take the width of the scroll view (not the content, the scroll view itself) and divide by 2. You have the center, but we need to compare it against the current position of our content. Use the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` compare it against the `frame` property in each `UIImageView` you put into the scroll view. Using `origin.x` and `size.width`

```
CGFloat center = self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2 + self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;
for (UIImageView *view in scrollViewImages) {
    CGFloat leftEdge = view.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat rightEdge = leftEdge + view.frame.size.width;

    // I didn't account the user stopping in a gap between images
    if (center >= leftEdge && center <= rightEdge) {
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:leftEdge+view.frame.size.width/2 animated:YES];
        self.selectedImage = view;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then just update image, `UIPageControl` and whatever you need to do.